# Help with the case $\mu(E) = \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

From Folland 's Analysis : Theorem 1.19 . Please give me some hints or the direction for the generalized case of $\mu(E) = \infty$

[image: Theorem 1.19]

$\mu$ is the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure. $M_\mu$ is the sigma algebra that contains all $\mu$ measurable sets.

Comment: Consider $E_n = E \cap [-n,n]$ and note $E = \bigcup E_n$.

Comment: Thanks, but I am still getting stuck. E is union of En , so I guess it must be related somehow to the Fsigma sets.

Comment: Yes, it's about writing $E$ as a union of an $F_\sigma$ and a null set. Each $E_n$ has finite measure, so $E_n = F_n \cup N_n$, now what?

Comment: Judging from your direction, do you use condition (c) from the theorem when En has finite measure ? In this case the union of En will equal the union of Fn and union of Nn. Union of Fn is a Fsigma set.

Comment: Right. A union of countably many $F_\sigma$s is an $F_\sigma$. And the union of countably many null sets?

Comment: It should be another null set. I will go and think how to prove (b).

Comment: Can I say this ? $E_n=V_n\N_n$ for each n. let V = $\cup V_n$ , so V is G delta set. V\E = $\cup N_n$ is the null set.

Comment: No, a countable union of $G_\delta$s need not be a $G_\delta$.

Comment: I run out of idea for (b), would you please give a little bit more hint ?

Comment: I'd not even try to prove it directly here. But if you know that $E \in \mathcal{M}_\mu$ and $a \iff c$, then $b$ is a breeze.

Comment: Does your suggestion  relate to the fact that $\mu$ is complete on $M_\mu$ ? I still don't see the connection very clearly.

Comment: Not really. Just to the fact that $E \in \mathcal{M}_\mu \iff \complement E \in \mathcal{M}_\mu$.

Comment: I see it now. $E = H \cup N_2$ , thus $E^C = H^C \cap {N_2}^C$. $H^C$ is a G delta set. Thus E= V\N1.

Comment: I mean I should start with $E^C = H\cup N $